# Bluebird .then(): no TypeError when function reference is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I recently started working with promises and found a strange behavior for me.
When i give the .then() function a reference to a undefined function it is just skipped and the next then is called.

An example:

```
var cust = customer({general: { cust_id: 22 }}); // just for testing
req.pool.getConnectionAsync()
        .then(cust.del) // cust.del is 'undefined'
        .then(function(dbResult) { console.log("dbresult:"); console.log(dbResult);  res.status(200).end(); })
        .catch(function (e) { console.log(e); res.status(500).end(); });
```

So what's happening here:

- getConnectionAsync returns a connection which should be given to cust.del
- cust.del is undefined (was a typo by me the correct function would be cust.delete)
- no error is raised instead the next .then function is called with the connection from getConnectionAsync as "dbresult"
- the output of the last then function is the connection object and not a db result object and status 200 is returned to the client

If i change the code to:

```
req.pool.getConnectionAsync()
        .then(function(conn) { cust.del(conn) }) // type error is raised
        .then(function(dbResult) { console.log("dbresult:"); console.log(dbResult); res.status(200).end(); })
        .catch(function (e) { console.log(e); res.status(500).end(); });
```

then i get the expected TypeError and the catch function is called.

Is this an expected behavior? Or am I missing something to prevent this?
.then(cust.del) is obviously much cleaner code, but since this function is not callable there should be an error.

Regards
Phil

Comment: It is the expected behavior: [Promises/A+: 2.2 The then Method](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-23):  `[...]2.2.1 Both onFulfilled and onRejected are optional arguments, 2.2.1.1 If onFulfilled is not a function, it must be ignored., 2.2.1.2 If onRejected is not a function, it must be ignored.[...]`

Comment: Thank you very much. I've missed that completely when I read this ... my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comment said, this is similar to:

```
Promise.resolve().then(undefined); // undefined is ignored here
```

It is specified in the Promises/A+ spec and it works this way in every promise implementation. The rationale was that Promises/A+ don't have to support a `.catch` method and you could do:

```
Promise.reject().then(null, function(err){ /* handle */ });
```

As well as interoperability with existing libraries.

Comment: A `console.warn`ing if neither argument is passed would be nice, though.

Comment: @Bergi open [an issue](http://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues). I'm not sure what good use case there is for a `.then` without any handlers - it still returns a new promise (so I guess there are cases for cancellation where it might be useful) but I'm honestly not sure. I wonder if there should be a strict build of bluebird that does not allow these sort of things.

Comment: @Bergi `this.then()` is used several times internally :D A warning could be good for non-function value that is not a null or undefined though because that is 99.99% surely a mistake however it wouldn't have helped this specific OP but many others that pass promise to .then.

Comment: @Esailija: `.then()` without arguments to create a copy is fine. I thought more of [this kind of warning](https://github.com/bergus/F/blob/cb3d050fa871406cadf28a873cf04700d09347bf/promise/Promise.js#L396), as I already [have one for promises](https://github.com/bergus/F/blob/cb3d050fa871406cadf28a873cf04700d09347bf/promise/Promise.js#L358)

Comment: @Bergi yea I think warning when > 0 arguments are passed and none are functions is fine... btw your code checks `typeof xx == null`: D

Comment: @Esailija: Argh, I had `typeof xx != "function"` at first but then figured that non-function values would already trigger the other warning(s) in `Promise.method`. Thanks for the quick heads-up, fixed it already :-)

Comment: Added in 2.9.5 https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/commit/c352c3760422adae611fbf486ae96a5be308d27a